# Jacobian Matrix at a non-singular point

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, singularity, motivation

I am currently studying singularities in Algebraic Geometry and wanted to understand why the rank of the Jacobian matrix would characterise a point of singularity/non-singularity (assuming we start off with singularities through some geometric motivation)?
What is the reason behind looking at the rank of the Jacobian matrix? Why should a point whose Jacobian matrix has rank $n-r$ be a non-singular point?

Since in Algebraic Geometry, we are working with arbitrary [algebraically closed] fields, it will be hard to visualise, but a differential geometric explanation will also do.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The same reason that $u=x^3$ is invertible at 0 even though the derivative is 0 there.

Comment: I assume you're talking about a subvariety of codimension $r$. The answer to your question is, very simply, the implicit function theorem. When the rank condition holds, your subvariety is locally the graph of a smooth function.

Comment: For an variety $X\subset \Bbb A^n_k$ defined over a field $k$, the tangent space $T_pX$ at a point $p\in X$ is naturally a subspace of the tangent space $T_p\Bbb A^n_k$. This subspace is exactly the kernel of the Jacobian matrix, so if the Jacobian matrix is of rank $n-r$, then the tangent space is of dimension $r$ - if the variety $X$ is of dimension $r$ at $p$, then this means that $X$ is nonsingular at $p$.

Comment: @KReiser thank you very much. That helped a lot!

Comment: @AbhijitAJ Great, I've upgraded my comment in to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me upgrade my comment in to an answer.

For an variety $X\subset \Bbb A^n_k$ defined over a field $k$, the tangent space $T_pX$ at a point $p\in X$ is naturally a subspace of the tangent space $T_p\Bbb A^n_k$. This subspace is exactly the kernel of the Jacobian matrix, so if the Jacobian matrix is of rank $n−r$, then the tangent space is of dimension $r$ - if the variety $X$ is of dimension $r$ at $p$, then this means that $X$ is nonsingular at $p$.